# Send SystemVerilog $display to stderr

Tags: stdout, verilog, system-verilog, stderr, verilator

I am using [Verilator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilator) to incorporate an algorithm written in SystemVerilog into an executable utility that manipulates I/O streams passed via `stdin` and `stdout`.  Unfortunately, when I use the SystemVerilog `$display()` function, the output goes to `stdout`.  I would like it to go to `stderr` so that `stdout` remains uncontaminated for my other purposes.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @toolic for pointing out the existence of `$fdisplay()`, which can be used thusly...

```
$fdisplay(STDERR,"hello world"); // also supports formatted arguments
```

IEEE Std 1800-2012 states that `STDERR` should be pre-opened, but it did not seem to be known to Verilator.  A workaround for this is:

```
integer STDERR = 32'h8000_0002;
```

Alternatively, you can create a log file handle for use with `$fdisplay()` like so...

```
integer logfile;
initial begin
   $system("echo 'initial at ['$(date)']'>>temp.log");
   logfile = $fopen("temp.log","a"); // or open with "w" to start fresh
end
```

It might be nice if you could create a custom wrapper that works like `$display` but uses your selected file descriptor (without specifying it every time).  Unfortunately, [that doesn't seem to be possible within the language itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12852771/86967) -- but maybe you can do it with the [DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemVerilog_DPI), see [DPI Display Functions](http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilator/Manual-verilator#dpi_display_functions) (I haven't gotten this to work so far).

Comment: STDERR wasn't already existing here on VCS SystemVerilog. I found on wikipedia that the file descriptor numbers/integers are normally `STDOUT == 1` and `STDERR == 2`... using `$fdisplay(1, "Hello World")` worked great here.